# Russian characters won't show up in Mozilla

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, http-headers

Could some on please check out this URL with Mozilla - http://smartplast.com/soon/ .

As you can see characters is displaying wrong :

[image]

I don't understand where is problem, cause in all other browsers content is displaying right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server response HTTP header has encoding "windows-1251", but the page itself is encoded in "UTF-8".

Here is your header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.8.53
Date: Mon, 23 Jan 2012 10:11:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Mon, 23 Jan 2012 10:03:18 GMT
ETag: "33c0537-2e1-4b72f23c06580"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 737
```

You can either set correct encoding in HTTP response header, or change encoding on the page.

Comment: To which encoding I have to change this index.html file?

Comment: The encoding must be the same on the page and in the header.